# Was bedeutet "in jemandem sterben" in einem religiösen Zusammenhang?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase

Ich kenne eine Arie von J. S. Bach, deren Titel »Stirb in mir, Welt, und alle deine Liebe« lautet. Ich habe das auch irgendwo anders gehört, in dem Text eines Liedes. Was bedeutet das? Gibt es eine englische Entsprechung dafür?

Ich habe schon mal versucht, den Ausdruck »in jemandem sterben« zu googeln, aber mit Anführungszeichen gab es keine Ergebnisse. Ich vermute, dass er veraltet ist, aber ich würde trotzdem gerne wissen, was das bedeutet.

Comment: *Arie* anstelle *Lied* klingt besser :) (und es muss auch so sein).

Comment: Danke. Ich hätte das wissen sollen weil ich morgen meine Deutschprüfung habe, in der ich einen Aufsatz über Bach schreiben muss!

Comment: Viel Erfolg und gutes Gelingen - oder [„Mast- und Schotbruch“](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hals-_und_Beinbruch), wie man hierzulande auch sagt :-)

Comment: Vielen Dank und danke für die Antwort, sehr hilfreich :)

Comment: Siehe auch *die Hoffnung stirbt zuletzt*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neben der direkten Bedeutung (Lebensende eines Menschen oder eines Tieres) kann man das Verb "sterben" auch metaphorisch oder in einem anthropomorphen Kontext verwenden. Im Text der [Bach-Kantate BWV 169 „Gott soll allein mein Herze haben“](http://www.bach-cantatas.com/Texts/BWV169-Eng3.htm) (modern umformuliert: „Nur Gott soll mein Herz besitzen“ oder auch „Mein Herz soll allein Gott gehören“) wünscht der Sprecher, seine Sünden, Missetaten und Fehler mögen „sterben“ und damit völlig aus seinem Herzen ausgelöscht werden. Die „Welt“ steht hier in einer Reihe mit den trügerischen, falschen Begehrlichkeiten und Wünschen, sie fasst quasi all dies zusammen. Erst wenn das Herz derart „gereinigt“ ist, kann es – biblisch gesprochen – ganz Gott gehören.

Der Kontext dieser Verwendung von „sterben“ ist zwar religiös; das ist aber nicht zwingend. Häufiger liest man etwa, dass in jemandem „alle Hoffnung (auf Rettung, auf Hilfe etc.) *stirbt*“. Dies ist eine noch bildhaftere, intensivere Formulierung für „die Hoffnung verlieren“. Diese Art der Formulierung kann auch losgelöst von einer bestimmten Person verwendet werden (dann eher in der Form „[ersterben](http://www.dwds.de/cache/shortcuts/ersterben.html)“): „Das Gemurmel im Saal erstarb, als XY eintrat.“

Comment: Was ist der Grund für den Downvote? Ich lerne gerne dazu - aber so ist das eine ziemlich feige Aktion. Ich habe ja eine Vermutung, aber...

Answer (score 4):

Read further, and you will understand:

> **Stirb** in mir,
>   Die in me,
>
> **Hoffart, Reichtum, Augenlust,**
>   arrogance, wealth and greedy lust of the eyes,
>
> Ihr verworfnen Fleischestriebe!
>   you abject promptings of the flesh.

He wants his "promptings of the flesh" (which are inside him) to die, i.e. to vanish. Same holds for "the world and all its loves", which he has internalized in some way. (Interpretation here, but essentially, that's it.) Furthermore I don't think a religious context is obligatory.

Analogously: "Erwache in mir, oh Lebenslust!"

Comment: "greedy lust of the eyes" -- huh? I'm not sure what the word means, here or at all, but that sounds clunky.

Comment: 1) It's not my translation, see link in chosen answer. 2) It's not about the translation.

Answer (score 1):

It makes about as much sense in English as in German:

> Die in me, world, and all your love.

Make of that what you want.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a proper answer. Now we still don't know what it means.

Comment: Yes I have no clue what that means in English!

Comment: Welcome to the club. I don't really know what it's supposed to mean in German, either. Which probably means it's no longer a language issues as such.

Comment: The question was initially tagged [tag:old-german]. Your answer doesn't provide anything useful in respect of the question, so -1 from me.